# Core data. Not persisting through app termination

Tags: ios, core-data

So, i finally got Core Data to work as intended. Saving stuff, and loading it within a UITableView subclass. Works perfectly as long as the application is running or in the background.

But as soon as the app is terminated (not uninstalled), and reopened, the data seems lost, or rather reset to nothing(when i load the NSManagedObjects to my array, i still get the correct amount - the properties are just nil)...

I save the context in:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Besides that, the App-Delegate is 100% Core-Data boilerplate code, except for the method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I could paste some code, but i wouldn't know what might be interesting...

Any suggestions?

----------EDIT----------

Code for saving new instances:

```
// create new screenshot and save
ScreenshotInfo *newScreenshot = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ScreenshotInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
newScreenshot.date = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
newScreenshot.note = @"click to add note...";
newScreenshot.thumbnailData = [self createThumbnailDataFromImage:image];
PicForScreenshot *newPic = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PicForScreenshot" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
newScreenshot.pic = newPic;
newPic.image = screenshotData;
newPic.info = newScreenshot;
NSError *error;
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Code for loading:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ScreenshotInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
pics = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (!pics) {
    [NSException raise:@"Fetch failed" format:@"reAson: %@",[error localizedDescription]];
}
```

Code for populating tableViewCells:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
CellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellView"];
ScreenshotInfo *currentPic = [pics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[[cell image]setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:currentPic.thumbnailData]];
[[cell noteLabel]setText:currentPic.note];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:currentPic.date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma"];
[[cell dateLabel]setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
return cell;
```

}

This should be the interesting code..

The instances are created and saved in one ViewController, and loaded into another one (the UITableViewController).

@Tommy, you say you're sure that the saving is somehow wrong, but how can the TableView fetch it correctly  immediately after creation, if the saving is not right.

Comment: Have you called `[context save]` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, i do that in
    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: If the save takes a non-trivial amount of time and you perform it in `applicationDidEnterBackground:` then your app may be killed for being non-responsive, before the save completes. In the natural course of things does it seem like your app is coming back from the background successfully or does it appear to have been terminated and restarted?

Comment: Do you check that the save completes without error?

Comment: Is there a reason you wait to save the data? There's a bunch of things that can go wrong with the app to make you lose state. As long as you're not trying to write 1000 saves individually continuously, you should look to save right after you make edits to an object. Also look in your Applications folder for your sqlite DB that is created by Core Data. See if there's any data in the actual DB.

Comment: @Tommy, The app seems to transition as intended between states. Also, like i said, it is not the background mode that cause the odd incident, but app-termination.

Comment: @LyricalPanda Actually now that you mention it, i do save the newly created instances right away, which makes the save in the app delegate useless(since there's no updating and such).

How do i find the "Applications folder for my SQLite DB"? 

Thanks all for the response so far. 
A note: My app supports background location updates. Don't know how that would affect it, but now its out there.

Comment: @Anders still having data after being in the background tells us nothing whatsoever, other than that you're definitely failing to save. Show some code.

Comment: @Tommy, Thank you for you reply, i edited OP.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Create the object graphic representation inside the project's .xcdatamodeld file. Set the attributes and relationships.

[image]

2 - Select the entity and click in Editor menu and select `Create NSManagedObject Subclass...`

[image]

3 - Create new entity instance by setting its context.

`var entity: Entity = Entity(context: self.context)`

4 - Access/recover an existing NSManaged object graphic entity
by the context calling the `Persistent Store Coordinator` method for the managed object graphic ID using its URL ID.

`let objectGraphID = self.context.persistentStoreCoordinator?.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: URL(string: "entityObjectGraphicID"))`

[image: core data stack relationship]

`let nodeEntity = self.context.persistentStoreCoordinator?.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: objIDURL!)`

Find more about Core Data here:
https://cocoacasts.com/exploring-the-core-data-stack

imageFont: https://cocoacasts.com/exploring-the-core-data-stack